# How setup Rewrite URL for IdentityServer hosted on Virtual Directory in Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, url-rewriting, .net-core, identityserver4

I'm deploying IdentityServer inside of a Virtual Directory inside of an Azure App Service. A custom domain `auth.mydomain.com` is pointing to the `myappservice.azurewebsites.net`. 
[image]
Within my `web.config` inside of the `wwwroot` of the app service I have following Rewrite Rule set.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>

        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite to Auth" stopProcessing="true"> 
                <match url="^(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^auth.mydomain.com$" />

                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="auth/{R:0}" />
            </rule>            
        </rules>

    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

If I access `https://auth.mydomain.com/.well-known/openid-configuration`, every URL has a trailing sitename, in my case `/auth`.

```
{
  "issuer":"https://auth.mydomain.com/auth",
   ...
}
```

Similar to the actual MVC app. Every link has the trailing /auth, if I remove it, the site loads just as expected, however every link generated from asp contains the /auth path.

How do I have to configure IdentityServer to omit the trailing sitename and just use auth.mydomain.com as the base?